# C# sort text file that has separator from high to low

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a console application that sorts out a logs from the specified text file from high to low.

Log example:

```
Sheila Moore | 0001:05912 | BSIT | Number: 20
Jake Aloma | 0001:05913 | BSIT | Number: 21
Julius Cesar | 0001:05915 | BSIT | Number: 22
```

I'd like to sort them out and writeline from high to low based on "Number" which is the very last.

Here is my code that I've done so far but it doesn't do what I wanted to achieve.

```
string[] lists = File.ReadAllLines(file.txt);

foreach (string log in lists.OrderBy(x => x.Split('|').Last()))
{
   Console.WriteLine(log);
}
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is:

```
Julius Cesar | 0001:05915 | BSIT | Number: 22
Jake Aloma | 0001:05913 | BSIT | Number: 21
Sheila Moore | 0001:05912 | BSIT | Number: 20
```

In descending order. I don't know if OrderBy method is the best approach for that kind of task.

Any help would be really appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Replace  lists.OrderBy with lists.OrderByDescending.

Comment: I edited it, my mistake with the ascending word. I got confused when typing.

Comment: Yea I see it working with lists.OrderByDescending(x => x.Split('|').Last()))

Comment: Are you sure? @RyanSchlueter because what I get is different :/

Comment: `OrderByDescending()` on the `string` (not on the number) will not sort numerically, but alphabetically by the string

Comment: @Reanna - your problem (which is why a few people's incorrect suggestions are throwing you off here) is that it will sort it, by default, alphabetically - not numerically.

Comment: Yes it's doing alphabetically and I don't know why, my friend recommended me stackoverflow and told me to look for some help here about this. @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//this will use MUCH less memory
var lines = File.ReadLines("file.txt");

foreach (string log in lines.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('|').Last().Replace("Number: ", "").Trim()) * -1))
{
   Console.WriteLine(log);
}
```

Comment: Similar to mine, and also a valid solution. Don't know who downvoted you, but I'll upvote to compensate

Comment: Hi. You're a genius! It did what I'm trying to achieve. Earlier it was doing alphabetically. Convert.ToInt32 sure does the thing and by the way, I'm not the one who gave you -1. Thanks alot ;)

Comment: the -1 is probably for the `* -1` vs `OrderByDesc()`. That's a choice. In my opinion, if you've already got an integer or double, the `* -1` is just as good. If you're ordering by text or date, changing the function makes more sense, but others may disagree. It could also be for `Convert()` rather than `TryParse()`.  I'm not worried about it :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I got a downvote using `OrderByDescending()` instead of `* -1`. Maybe the `Convert` too? ;-) (not worried either, just... surprised :-) )

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there... you need to get the actual number (and sort by a number and descend) from the last column, so this should work:

```
foreach (string log in lists.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('|').Last().Split(new [] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1])))
{
  Console.WriteLine(log);
}
```

You should also use `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines` if you plan to have the file open during the enumeration (so it doesn't have to read the whole file in one go)